# Continuous Playing of Different Video Files in a VLC Playlist

Tags: c#, vlc

I am trying to play different video files continuously on VLC player on my Winform application.

The problem I face is between different playlist videos there is a 1-2 seconds of black screen.

How can I play all videos in my playlist smoothly without any waiting?

```
private void buttonLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Val\Downloads\000013.ts");
            var converted = uri.AbsoluteUri;
            var uri2 = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Val\Downloads\000210.ts");
            var converted2 = uri2.AbsoluteUri;
            axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(converted);
            axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(converted2);
}

private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axVLCPlugin21.MediaPlayerEndReached += new EventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            axVLCPlugin21.playlist.playItem(0);
}

private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axVLCPlugin21.playlist.playItem(1);

        }
```

this is a simplified version of what I am trying to do. 
When the player reaches end of the first video file it starts the second on by eventhandler function.

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know to play videos seamlessly is to avoid the timed event in your example:

```
private void buttonLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            var uri = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Val\Downloads\000013.ts");
            var converted = uri.AbsoluteUri;
            var uri2 = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Val\Downloads\000210.ts");
            var converted2 = uri2.AbsoluteUri;
            axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(converted);
            axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(converted2);
}

private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
}
```

Comment: No I have not found